# Rails - I18n -  How to localize a collection of symbols in f.collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out how to localize a list of symbols in a collection_select helper.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   bitmask :regions, :as => [:north, :south, :est, :west]     
end
```

in form :

```
 <tr>
    <th><%= f.label :regions %></th>
    <td><%= f.collection_select :regions, User.values_for_regions, :to_s, :to_s %></td>
  </tr>
```

I am not sure I have a good understanding of the fourth argument. Can it be customized ?
I would like to display a localized string for each element in the collection (User.values_for_regions returns [:north, :south, :est, :west]).
I18n.t(:to_s) does not evaluate the symbol but the string "to_s". How can I access each symbol of the collection to apply the t method ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party, but here's an answer for all of those who may come across this question once in a while.

As a `text_method` we can pass in a Proc that takes care of our translation:

```
<%= f.collection_select :regions, User.values_for_regions, :to_s, Proc.new { |val| I18n.t(val, scope: 'activerecord.attributes') } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've used the Enumerize gem to fix this problem. have a look on their Github. The installation is pretty straightforward and easy to install with I18n localize file.

https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize